# Getting different

Tags: vue.js, prop

I have a problem related to Vue.js probs (I guess). I have a chart which fetches data in the `created()` from an API which looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <highcharts if="data.length > 0" :options="chartOptions" ></highcharts>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import exportingInit from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

exportingInit(Highcharts);

export default {
  props: {
    partsdata: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
    created() {
      this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/')
      .then(response => {
        var result = JSON.parse(response.data)
        return result
      }).then(data => {
        var result = data.Fare 
        console.log(result) // eslint-disable-line no-console
        this.chartOptions.series[0].data = [] // Array wieder zurücksetzen
      for(var key in result) {
          this.chartOptions.series[0].data.push(result[key]) // eslint-disable-line no-console
      } 
      })
    },
  components: {
    highcharts: Chart
  },

  data() {
    return {
      data: [],
      chartOptions: {
        title: {
          text: 'Title aligned left',
          align: 'left',
          x: 0
        },
        series: [{
          type: "column",
          data: [] // sample data
        }]
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
  .btn-primary {
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    background: white;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

This is my parent component, where I use my Charts, which works fine.

```
<template>
  <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-card dark color="white">
          <v-card-text class="px-0">
             <Highcharts></Highcharts>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-card dark color="white">
          <v-card-text class="px-0">
             <Highcharts></Highcharts>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-card dark color="white">
          <v-card-text class="px-0">
              <Highcharts></Highcharts>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs6>
        <v-card dark color="white">
          <v-card-text class="px-0">
              <Highcharts></Highcharts>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Highcharts from "./Header.vue"

export default {
  components: {
    Highcharts: Highcharts
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

However, what I want is to fetch the data **from different Endpoints** without creating a ton of new components. Is there a way to use the `created()` lifecycle hook as props or are there any other clever solutions how to archieve this?

Comment: Have you tried passing the endpoint as a prop to your Highcharts component?

Comment: sounds good :-)